# How to implement debounce fn into jQuery keyup event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

A calculation is based on user input, and criteria is to use `keyup` rather than `change` or `blur`.

The problem is that the code fires on every keystroke, and I need it to delay and fire only once after a 500ms timeout. My example below obviously doesn't work, fiddle attached.

I found David Walsh's `dbounce` function, but cannot figure out how to implement it.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kkoosvro/)

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" />
<input type="text" id="n2" class="num" value="17" disabled />
<input type="text" id="n3" class="num" value="32" disabled />
```

**javascript/jQuery:**

```
$('input').keyup(function(){
    var $this=$(this);
    setTimeout(function(){
        var n1 = $this.val();
        var n2 = $('#n2').val();
        var n3 = $('#n3').val();
        var calc = n1 * n2 * n3;
        alert(calc);
    },500);
});

//http://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function
function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
    var timeout;
    return function() {
        var context = this, args = arguments;
        var later = function() {
            timeout = null;
            if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
        };
        var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
        if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
    };
};
```

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Use it like this:-

```js
$('input').keyup(debounce(function(){
    var $this=$(this);
    //alert( $this.val() );
    var n1 = $this.val();
    var n2 = $('#n2').val();
    var n3 = $('#n3').val();
    var calc = n1 * n2 * n3;
    alert(calc);
},500));
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bjb9s2w5/)

Comment: great, this worked for me with underscore's `_.debounce()` function.

Comment: works as described using the OP's supplied debounce function.

Comment: _.debounce() function works for me as well. Thanks a lot @nnyby and squiroid.